# Separate values from category in the same column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a column that looks like this

```
value 
Ford
2,300
Chevy
15
Toyota
245
```

And I want to transform it and I'm looking for something like this

```
Brand     Value
Ford      2,300
Chevy     15
Toyota    245
```

What's the best way to get here using a tidyvere solution?

Answer (score 3):

If these are alternate elements, easier option is to use a recycling logical vector to extract in `base R`

```
data.frame(Brand = df1$value[c(TRUE, FALSE)], Value = df1$value[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
   Brand Value
1   Ford 2,300
2  Chevy    15
3 Toyota   245
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(value = c("Ford", "2,300", "Chevy", "15", "Toyota", 
"245")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `dplyr::summarize()` with @akrun's simple solution.

```r
library(dplyr)

summarize(df1, Brand = value[c(T, F)], value = value[c(F, T)])
#>    Brand value
#> 1   Ford 2,300
#> 2  Chevy    15
#> 3 Toyota   245
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `lag()` and filter out:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(Brand = lag(value)) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %% 2 == 0) %>% 
  select(Brand, Value=value)
```

```
   Brand Value
1   Ford 2,300
2  Chevy    15
3 Toyota   245
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  value = c("Ford", "2,300", "Chevy", "15", "Toyota", "245")
)

df %>% 
  mutate(name = rep(c("brand", "value"), n()/2)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_fn = list) %>% unnest(everything())

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   brand  value
#>   <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 Ford   2,300
#> 2 Chevy  15   
#> 3 Toyota 245
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `unstack` for alternating rows. I create a sequence by alternating ids (i.e., Brand and Value).

```
unstack(transform(df, val = c("Brand", "Value")), value ~ val)
```

**Output**

```
   Brand Value
1   Ford 2,300
2  Chevy    15
3 Toyota   245
```

Here is another `tidyverse` option, where I create a sequence using `rep` to put every other row into a group. Then, I split the dataframe into separate dataframes for every alternate row. Then, I bind the columns back together.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ind = rep(c(1, 2),length.out = n())) %>%
  group_split(., .keep = FALSE) %>% 
  bind_cols(.name_repair = "minimal") %>% 
  rename("Brand" = 1, "Value" = 2)
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(value = c("Ford", "2,300", "Chevy", "15", "Toyota", 
"245")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```